# Redirect problem for usernames with certain Unicode characters in them

Tags: bug, status-completed

Trying to access [this user's page](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/users/544/) leads to a "The page isn't redirecting properly" error for me using both Firefox and Chrome. I'm thinking there might be a problem with the handling of URLs for usernames that have certain Unicode characters in them.

Comment: This is not related to the reported issue itself, but in case you report other similar problems in the future, the characters in the English alphabet are also “Unicode characters.”

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto You made a point, but I don't think cypher is entirely wrong. The problem may indeed be the program's handeling of Unicode characters. The English alphabet do not cause problems not because they are not Unicode characters but because they are ASCII characters as well, which the programs can handle. And I think cypher's intention may be that.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto fair enough, I've replaced it with "certain Unicode characters."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link above now works so it looks like it's been fixed, though I'm not sure on the details.