# Redirect problem for a specific question

Tags: bug, status-completed

**Edit**: The original bug still remains, but I've worked around the issue for the time being by removing the trailing `U+3000 IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE` from the title of the question (see the answer below for more information.)

---

I'm having some redirect problems which prevent me from viewing the question #6458: ["Adverbial form: 楽しみに　or 楽しみで　?"](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/6458/adverbial-form-%E6%A5%BD%E3%81%97%E3%81%BF%E3%81%AB%E3%80%80or-%E6%A5%BD%E3%81%97%E3%81%BF%E3%81%A7%E3%80%80).

Firefox, Opera and Chrome all gave a "The page isn't redirecting properly" error or similar and IE8 went on for a long time before eventually producing the below error.

Chrome gave the following:

> This webpage has a redirect loop
> The webpage at [Adverbial form: 楽しみに or 楽しみで?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/6458/adverbial-form-%e6%a5%bd%e3%81%97%e3%81%bf%e3%81%ab%e3%80%80or-%e6%a5%bd%e3%81%97%e3%81%bf%e3%81%a7%e3%80%80) has resulted in too many redirects. Clearing your cookies for this site or allowing third-party cookies may fix the problem. If not, it is possibly a server configuration issue and not a problem with your computer.

The message I got after trying this in Internet Explorer 8.0 was:

> We're sorry...
>
> There are an unusual number of requests coming from this IP address.
>
> To protect our users, we can't process any more requests from this IP address right now.
>
> We'll restore access as quickly as possible, so try again soon.
>
> If you believe you have reached this page in error, contact us.

I think it might possibly be an issue with Unicode similar to [Redirect problem for usernames with certain Unicode characters in them](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/589/redirect-problem-for-usernames-with-certain-unicode-characters-in-them).

Comment: Also possibly related: [Question is inacessible due to invalid utf-8 character in a title](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/566/question-is-inacessible-due-to-invalid-utf-8-character-in-a-title)

Comment: I added the error from Chrome

Comment: @jkerian: I guess that Stack Exchange rewrote the URL in the error message to make it readable (unfortunately in this case).

Comment: Hmm... it rewrites it, but I still can't follow the re-written link. Curiously enough, the redirect even prevents you from opening the link if you remove everything after the 6458.

Comment: Safari gives me "Too many redirects" and can't open that page.  I can't even open it after trimming the part after the question number.

Comment: @jkerian, Troyen: apparently you couldn't visit it that way, but it looks like you could visit/edit the question using it's revision page at http://japanese.stackexchange.com/posts/6458/revisions. For the time being, I've edited the question's title so it's not affected by the bug which I describe in my answer below.

Comment: [We're seeing a similar issue on French.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233850/redirect-loop-after-editing-a-question-title-ending-with-no-break-space-questio). It seems that something doesn't like trailing Unicode characters, or at least some of them.

Comment: Here's an explanation of the messages you're seeing. When you link to a question, the title (with most punctuation stripped) appears to the URL. If you hit the right question number with the wrong title, you get redirected to the URL with the right title. In this instance, the software that SE is using trips up and sends a redirection to the same URL instead of the page content.

Comment: *(cont.)* Most browsers detect that the page is redirecting to itself and give up. IE just keeps going forever, until the SE server decides that your machine has been making too many requests and boots you off.

Comment: This should be fixed now - pretty sure it is (as noted by senshin) the same as http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233868/23354

Answer (score 5):

By experimenting, I've figured out this issue was caused by the `U+3000 IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE` before the question mark in the title (`Adverbial form: 楽しみに　or 楽しみで　?`) not being stripped properly. I was able to trigger a recursive redirect by creating a new question with the following title:

`trailing ideographic spaces bug demo`　 (note the final "　")

I deleted it to try to minimize load on Stack Exchange's servers, but moderators and users with over 2000 reputation can view a demonstration of this issue at https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/903.